# Make a simple notification seen when I background my application

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how to make a notification that notify  the user that he background the application.

Comment: welcome, it is standard that you first make an effort and post that effort in your question before you start asking the community. See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onPause()` method of the activity.And have to trigger a `notification`.

For Notification see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). Also you can see Activity life cycle from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods are called when brought to the background and into the foreground again, however thay are also called when the application is started for the first time and before it is killed. You can read more here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Here are notification Example as your question.

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification myNotification;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_action_search,
                "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notificationTitle = "Exercise of Notification!";
        String notificationText = "http://android-er.blogspot.com/";
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle,
                notificationText, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do this in onStop() and onStart() instead of onPause() and onResume().
Otherwise your Notification will be called each time you have something brought on top of your activity but your activity is still visible (for example a popup pops up because you've received an SMS...), that brings up in front of your activity.
The onPause() will be called in that case, not the onStop().